# Individual stylesheets must be in the sass directory

Tags: symfony, sass, assetic, compass

I am trying to setup symfony2 to compile sass files.

However every time i run `php app/console assetic:dump` i get the following error:

```
Individual stylesheets must be in the sass directory.
```

This is what my main.scss looks like:

```
@import "utilities/variables";

@import "base/layout";
@import "base/footer";
@import "base/modules";
@import "base/form";
@import "base/button";
@import "base/plugin-overrides";

@import "utilities/loaders";
```

There is no plain css in any of those files, i tried commenting everything but it keeps throwing the error.

I am rendering everything using this:

```
{% block stylesheets %}
    {% stylesheets
        filter='compass'
        'bundles/mybundle/styles/main.scss'
    %}
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset_url }}"/>
    {% endstylesheets %}
{% endblock %}
```

Which should pick up the file and compile using the filter `compass`

My configuration for assetic looks like this:

```
assetic:
    debug:          "%kernel.debug%"
    use_controller: false
    bundles:        [ 'MaximCMSBundle' ]
    #java: /usr/bin/java
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
        sass: ~
        compass: ~
```

And i have defined the correct paths for compass and sass in the parameters:

```
ruby.path: 'C:\Ruby200-x64\bin'
assetic.filter.sass.bin: 'C:\Ruby200-x64\bin\sass'
assetic.filter.compass.bin: 'C:\Ruby200-x64\bin\compass'
assetic.filter.compass.images_dir: '%kernel.root_dir%/../web/images'
assetic.filter.compass.http_path: /images
```

I am running the following versions:

SASS: `3.4.5`

Compass: `1.0.1`

When i rollback those versions to the following:

SASS: `3.2.19`

Compass: `0.12.7`

Everything works fine, however i would like to use the latest versions.

Comment: Same here... did you solve it already?

Comment: I'm using the older SASS and Compass version, i haven't tested since then

Answer (score 5):

The assetic filter needs a one line change to work with the newer version of Compass / Saas

Edit "vendor/kriswallsmith/assetic/src/Assetic/Filter/CompassFilter.php"

Change Line 312 from:

```
$pb->add('--sass-dir')->add('')->add('--css-dir')->add('');
```

to:

```
$pb->add('--sass-dir')->add($tempDir)->add('--css-dir')->add($tempDir);
```

That fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

After trying Indivision Dev's solution and others that I saw around the web, I solved this problem by clearing cache:

```
php app/console cache:clear -e prod
```